# Desempenho em uma tela com 26 formulários

Tags: desempenho

Tenho 26 formulários em uma única tela (Tela Geral) por causa de problemas que estava tendo ([aqui](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Store-scroll-state/m-p/1693157#M430890)). Eu uso uma galeria para chamar um formulário específico pelo título.

[image]

O problema é que quando preciso entrar na tela (Tela Geral) onde estão os 26 formulários, ocorre uma grande lentidão.

Não gostaria de ter que voltar a trabalhar com a forma anterior que usava, que eram 26 telas, uma para cada formulário (por causa do problema de rolagem citado no link acima), mas acabou causando essa lentidão inesperada.

Conversamos um pouco na comunidade da [Microsoft sobre isso](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Performance-on-a-screen-with-26-forms/m-p/1697456#M432104) e também coloquei no [Stack Overflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73208183/performance-on-a-screen-with-26-forms) tentando obter novas respostas. Se houver novas ideias/resoluções, fico agradecido.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No final, foi preferível antes da Tela Geral ter uma tela com 26 botões. Resolvido.